# How to give input matrix in Verilog code?

Tags: matrix, verilog

I am writing verilog code for inserting values in 4x4 matrix
I need to collect 16 input each one in a 4x4 matrix. How can I do that?

````
reg [15:0]fun_out;    
integer x, y;
always @(posedge clk or negede rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    for (x=0,x<4,x=x+1) begin
      for (y=0,y<4,y=y+1) begin
        data[0][0] <= fun_out[0];
        data[0][1] <= fun_out[1];
        data[0][2] <= fun_out[2];
        data[0][3] <= fun_out[3];
        data[1][0] <= fun_out[4];
        data[2][0] <= fun_out[5];
         ........
         ........
        data[4][3] <= fun_out[14];
        data[4][4] <= fun_out[15]; 
      end
    end
  end
  else begin
    data[x][y]<=4'b0;
  end
end ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that NUM_WIDTH is the amount of bits per value inside the matrix:

```
localparam NUM_WIDTH = 4;
localparam NUM_X = 4;
localparam NUM_Y = 4;
```

We can use "+:" to index a chunk of an array. Said that, we can pack and assign the data in every row of the matrix as:

```
genvar I, J;

wire [(NUM_WIDTH*NUM_X)-1:0] matrix [NUM_Y-1:0];

generate
  for(I = 0; I < 4; I = I + 1) begin: matrix_gen_y
    for(J = 0; J < 4; J = J + 1) begin: matrix_gen_x
      assign matrix[I][(J*NUM_WIDTH)+:NUM_WIDTH] = (I*NUM_X)+J+1; //..from 1 to 16
    end
  end
endgenerate
```

So, in order to index a value inside the matrix with "x" and "y" indexes:

```
assign value = matrix[y_idx][(x_idx*NUM_WIDTH)+:NUM_WIDTH];
```